# Is it possible to put else inside a function if the if statment is outside it?

Tags: python

So im trying to create a quiz for an assignment but i got tired writing if and else after every question to see if its right so i decided to try making a function.

The thing is that the if statement can't go inside the function as it needs check the users answer. 
What i tried to do looks something like

```
def result():
                    print("Correct")
              else:
                    print("Wrong")
```

I wanted to insert the function after an if statment but i just get a syntax error whenever I try to run it since there is no if statement to go before the else in the function.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: No, you can't do that. Functions don't "find and replace" code; each function must contain a complete block of valid Python code.

Comment: `else` without `if` is like jerry without tom. Won't work ;)

Comment: @Bazingaa not true, else can be used with for statement in python :)

Comment: I meant in the context of `if` but yeah you got me there ;)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're writing something like this over and over again:

```
if ask_question():
  print("Correct")
else:
  print("Wrong")
```

You *can* indeed move this repetitive logic into a function! That's a central premise of programming. But functions are (generally speaking) isolated units of work, because they're defined in one place and then invoked somewhere else. So, as you discovered, you can't define a function mid-way through an `if` statement.

What you can do, however, is move the whole `if` statement into your function! Consider:

```
def print_result(result):
  if result:
    print("Correct")
  else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Which you can pass `True` or `False` values into to trigger the different paths, e.g. `print_result(True)` and `print_result(False)`.

Perhaps you can figure out where to go from here :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass two variables to your function?

```
def result(entry, answer):
    if entry == answer:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Wrong')

result(20, 10)
result('bird', 'bird')
result('cat', 'dog')
result(5, 5)
```

I would also set up a dicitonary and give you some real utility for things like this :

```
def result(entry, answer):
    if entry == answer:
        print('Correct')
        scores['correct'] += 1
    else:
        print('Wrong')
        scores['wrong'] += 1
    scores['total'] += 1

scores = {'total': 0, 'correct': 0, 'wrong': 0}

result(20, 20)
result('bird', 'bird')
result('cat', 'dog')
percent = round((scores['correct']/scores['total'])*100, 2)
grade = print('Correct: {}'.format(scores['correct']) +
              '\nWrong: {}'.format(scores['wrong']) +
              '\nPercent: {}'.format(percent))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 helping.py 
> Correct
> Correct
> Wrong
> Correct: 2
> Wrong: 1
> Percent: 66.67
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def result(answer, right_answer):
    if answer == right_answer: print("Correct")
    else: print("Wrong")

>result("goose", "goose")
Correct

>result("cat", "goose")
Wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is pass the condition in as an argument as shown below

```
def result(cond):
    if cond:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Wrong')
```

what this does, it keeps your function standalone i.e, you don't need to care about the condition you pass, just what the condition evaluates to, probably letting you later reuse the function.

Sample Usage would include, just invoking the function with the condition; something like -

```
result(answer == 'answer placehoder')
```